# How to filter by space in filter as you type list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, spaces

I want to filter a list by typing a space (just like any other character).

The current code is:

```
var search = $.trim($(this).val().replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&"));
```

If I have `vege tables` in my list and I type a space, or letter `e` and space, or space and letter `t`, the list should filter to show `vege tables`.

I have tried to add \s to the code but it is not working as I had hoped:

```
var search = $.trim($(this).val().replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|\s]/g, "\\$&"));
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to filter a list of stings based on a pattern.

```
function filter(list, pattern) {
  return list.filter(function(item) {
    return pattern.test(item);
  });
}
const list = ['vege tables', 'man eater', 'word'];
console.log('Current list: ', list);

var pattern = ' e';
console.log('Filter by: "' + pattern + '"');

pattern = new RegExp(pattern, 'gi'); // convert the pattern to regex
console.log(filter(list, pattern)); // get filtered list, ['man eater']
```

Comment: Thanks for your example. How do I incorporate it into the existing code without adversely affecting the existing filtering? https://jsfiddle.net/djj2c84t/5/